# Determining values of multilinear forms/ differential forms

Tags: real-analysis, multilinear-algebra

I started getting into the topic of multilinear forms and differential forms.
I find it quite hard to get into.

if I solve $$ \Phi ( \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2\\3 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\5\\6 \end{pmatrix}) $$
$n=3 , \Phi= \triangle_{(1,2)}-2 \triangle_{(1,3)}+ 3 \triangle_{(2,3)} $

Is this way right?:

$$ \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 4\\ 2& 5 \end{vmatrix} - 2 \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 4\\ 3 & 6 \end{vmatrix} +3 \begin{vmatrix} 2 & 5\\ 3 & 6 \end{vmatrix}= -3+12-9=0$$

I am not sure how to deal with :

$$ ( df )( \pi , 0, \frac12 ) (\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ \frac{1}{ \pi} \\ \sqrt{3} \end{pmatrix} )$$

where $n=3 $ and

$ f(x,y,z)= \sin x+e^y \arccos z $

any ideas?

Comment: what is it $\triangle$?

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: take the gradient of  $f$ for $df$, evaluate at $(\pi,0,1/2)$ and matrix-multiply with the given column.

Comment: You may find [my lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd) somewhat helpful. See, in particular, the last half of MATH 3510.